# Populating Values to docuSign with POST

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I am trying to prepopulate values in with Form and POST i am not able to get the datas. The same coding is working with their documentation example.[image]

Here is my coding

```
<form action="https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER /PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=4576cc19-c2bf-47d5-a9fb-6b77142578d7" method="POST">
<p>Full Name : <input type="text" name="Customer_Email Address" value="myemail@email.com"></p>  
<p>Full Name : <input type="text" name="Customer_Full Name" value="myFullName"></p>  
<p>Full Name : <input type="text" name="Customer_Company" value="myCompany"></p>  
<p><input class="form_submit" type="submit" value="send"/></p>
</form>
```

Here is example coding copied from [docuSign](https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/question/adding-information-to-a-powerform-using-javascript)

```
<form action="https://demo.docusign.net/MEMBER/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=8968380d-16da-447c-97d7-fa989ed11082" method="POST">
<p><input type="text" name="Signer 1_Email" value="myemail@email.com"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="Signer 1_UserName" value="myFullName"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="OrderNumber" value="123456"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="CompanyName" value="myCompany"></p>
<p><input class="form_submit" type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

My Coding Snap-Shot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all replies. I need to create a custom label in docusign to work with. I found the solution.